# Negative RSquare Value but Good View on Chart for RNN Time Series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, r-squared, recurrent-neural-network, univariate

I'm fairly new on univariate time series forecasting and deep learning.
My task is to forecast energy consumption values.
May data looks like:
[image]

I'm usin simple RNN, because I have tested with linear regression, xgboost, lstm and rnn, but rnn looks the best.
I'm using Min-Max scaler to scale my data. and after predictions my actual vs prediction chart and training-loss chart looks like below:
[image]
[image]

Epoch is 1000.

But there is a big problem with the r2 metric.
It's -14.617

By the way my data is stationary. I've checked with ADF test.

When I check the chart it seems very well. But r2 is very bad.
I couldn't find an understandable explanation to my problem.
Is there anyone to help me to understand?
Thanks.

Comment: In what sense do you see your predictions as looking good? I can barely tell anything from the graph of predicted and actual values, but the little I can see makes it look like you have large misses on some of the large spikes.

Comment: I'm interpreting good because almost all values overlapping between actual and predicted. But like I have mentioned before, I'm also learning.

Comment: Do they overlap that well? You might benefit from plotting a thicker line in the background with a thinner line on top. You also might benefit from zooming in on the small waves in order to see if you consistently have small misses that you simple cannot see when you zoom out to fit the entire range of values in the graph.

Comment: $R^2$ is a number between 0 and 1. How come you get -14?

Comment: Yes I know R2 is between 0 and 1, that's why I'm researching the  reason of this situation.

Comment: @RichardHardy `sklearn`, for instance, calculates $R^2$ by $1-RSS/TSS$, rather than squaring a correlation. This is a reasonable statistic to calculate, even if the naming might leave something to be desired, as it flags a situation where the residual sum of squares for the model exceeds the total sum of squares by giving a value below zero.

Comment: @Dave, thanks. It makes sense. I am so used to models that are better than the unconditional mean that it is good to draw some attention to ones that are worse (waaay worse in this case).